# Не работает прыжок. Unity 2d

Tags: unity3d

Код вроде прописан правильно. Чека земли пока нет, весь код
В чем здесь ошибка?

```
public Rigidbody2D Player;
float speed = 5;
float move;
float jumpheight = 6.5f;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Движение героя 
   
    move = (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    Player.velocity = new Vector2(move, 0) * speed;

    Flip();
    Jump();
}

// Разворот героя
void Flip()                                                           
{
    if (move < 0)
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
    }
    else if (move > 0)
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;    
    }
    
}


// Прыжок 
void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        
        Player.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpheight ;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: добавил текстом

Comment: два вопроса: 1 - что делает эта строка: `Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`? 2 - почему везде используется `.velocity`, а не `AddForce` ?

Comment: 1. когда смотрел видео про прыжок, там так сделали. вы спросили - я понял, что она не нужна. потому что у меня к объекту rb прикреплен
2. код я подправил уже, да. теперь он выглядит вот так: 
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            
            Player.AddForce (Vector2.up * jumpheight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
прыжок есть, но новая проблема - он деревянный. думаю/ищу сейчас, как его сделать плавным и по дуге.
upd: код у меня в сообщении написан построчно, а здесь он переходит в сплошной. извините